# Como fazer entrada de dados na depuração com VS Code

Tags: c#, debug, visual-studio-code

Comecei a usar o VS Code para programar, to gostando bastante.

Mas numa simples aplicação de console, quando estou na depuração e chega em uma linha com `Console.ReadLine()` não da pra fazer a entrada de dados, eu escrevo no console, mas nada....

Se no console do depurador não for possível fazer as entradas de dados, tem como eu fazer em um console externo?

Comment: Cara não sei se te ajuda mas com o vs code vc consegue abrir varios consoles na raiz do projeto ou em pastas internas do projeto... Se quiser coloco um passo a passo ai pra vc. Só não sei se ele vai te ajudar com o problema que vc esta tendo aí. Mas abrir mais de um console no projeto eh moleza, tipo um rodando springboot e outro no git fazendo commit no repositório etc

Answer (score 2):

Conseguir o que queria seguindo [este tutorial](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window).
Basicamente o que fiz foi mudar no launch.json do VS code a linha com

```
"console": "internalConsole"
```

para

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

e partir dai em vez de usar o console do depurador eu utilizo o terminal comum, onde é possivel fazer entrada de dados.